# Swift PDF file not available from UIDocumentPickerViewController but available on files using xcode simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, delegates, ios-simulator

I want to import pdf file in xcode simulator but it is not available from UIDocumentPickerViewController and only available from files app.

Files app:

[image]

Files from UIDocumentPickerViewController:

[image]

My code:

```
let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [kUTTypeFolder as String], in: .open)
    documentPicker.delegate = self
    self.present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: You've only specified `kUTTypeFolder`, so it is natural that you only see folders. Also note that that initialiser is deprecated. Use `UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: [.pdf])` instead.

Comment: @Sweeper i cannot find UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: [.pdf]), is it not available in xcode 12.0.1?

Comment: [Available since iOS 14](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller/3566732-init). For previous versions you should fall back to your way, but specify the UTI for PDFs, rather than folders.

Comment: @Sweeper i tried using UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [kUTTypeFolder as String, kUTTypePDF as String], in: .open) but still no pdf files available

Answer (score 0):

please check the extension of the simulator file.

For .pdf, .doc, .docx.

```
import MobileCoreServices

let menu = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["com.microsoft.word.doc","org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.document", kUTTypePDF as String], in: UIDocumentPickerMode.import) 
menu.delegate = self 
self.present(menu, animated: true, completion: nil)
```